# How to get person in alfresco share through java?

Tags: spring, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new to alfresco community and I have created persons in alfresco community by using java.

But now i want to get that user data by using java. I am trying like below but it raises null pointer exception.

```
PersonServiceImpl personServiceImpl = new PersonServiceImpl();
        NodeRef nodeRef = personServiceImpl.getPerson("sobhan");
        System.out.println("Person Service imple "+nodeRef);
```

Error is

```
Aug 03, 2016 5:43:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'testing'
+==========================================
uplaod file 
Aug 03, 2016 5:43:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [testing] in context with path [/SpringWithAlfrescoScreens] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.person.PersonServiceImpl.getFromCache(PersonServiceImpl.java:1827)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.person.PersonServiceImpl.getPersonOrNullImpl(PersonServiceImpl.java:530)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.person.PersonServiceImpl.getPersonImpl(PersonServiceImpl.java:489)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.person.PersonServiceImpl.getPerson(PersonServiceImpl.java:476)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.person.PersonServiceImpl.getPerson(PersonServiceImpl.java:433)
    at com.plianto.dmsservice.DummyDmsService.perm(DummyDmsService.java:70)
    at com.service.AlfService.saveApplication(AlfService.java:116)
    at com.controller.AlfController.saveApplication(AlfController.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You shouldn't create a new `PersonServiceImpl` but inject the existing one in the configuration.

Comment: Sorry ,I am not understanding what you told. Please tell me clearly..

Comment: He means that PersonServiceImpl is a Spring Bean. You should inject it in your class instead of creating a new PersonServiceImpl().

Comment: Thank you Akah garu

Comment: I need to create bean for that class or any thing else to get that bean?

Answer (score 1):

I resume and answer here since it is difficult to post code in comments :

As Walfrat said :

> You shouldn't create a new PersonServiceImpl but
>   inject the existing one in the configuration.

because the person service is handled by Spring.

In your context file, for your service `com.plianto.dmsservice.MyService`, you should declare the existing person service this way :

```
<bean id="dummyDmsService" class="com.plianto.dmsservice.DummyDmsService">
    <property name="personService">
        <ref bean="PersonService" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then in your class :

```
public class DummyDmsService{
    private PersonService personService;

    /**
     * @return the personService
     */
    public final PersonService getPersonService() {
        return personService;
    }

    /**
     * @param pPersonService
     *            the personService to set
     */
    public final void setPersonService(final PersonService pPersonService) {
        personService = pPersonService;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting  "No bean named 'personService' is defined"

Comment: Are you in an alfresco context ? Did you used an Uppercase for PersonService ?

Comment: I meant, are you making an amp ? http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-amp-intro.html. Did you declared your service in your module-context.xml ? Or are you in an external application ? If so, we will need more information about your code.

Comment: I am in external appliaction

Comment: Actually I have deployed alfresco and share into separate server(I mean Alfresco community installed in separate system) and i am accessing that from my spring mvc application.

Comment: How are you connecting to the alfresco application then ? I need this information to give a better explaination.

Comment: I am connecting to alfresco by using rest support and i have been creating folders and document by using apache cmis jars into alfresco repository..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119017/discussion-between-manohar-and-akah).